# How do I update CSV file into mysql Database?

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, webmin

Hello I wondering is there way I can update a CSV file into mysql database. At this current time I have created a database in mysqlworkbench which connected to mysql sever. Then I upload CSV file into database which updates auto on webmin webserver.

The question I want to ask is how can I link new CSV file onto the database automatically.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times here and load data infile is clearly explained in the documetantaion

Answer (score 1):

Create database table with same numbers of columns present in the csv file.

Run following query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/import.csv' INTO TABLE <table> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: Good question but obviously mysql editor :) Take a look http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html.